# Ignore hidden rows in a spreadsheet after autofilter applied

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find a code that will ignore hidden rows on a spreadsheet that is used to auto-fill PDF forms after the user has the data filtered.  I do not want to delete the hidden rows or the information the user has entered in the hidden rows.

I have found several codes that work however I can't test them properly as I'm not certain I'm adding the said code in the correct part of the code. I was advised using .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) as per below can assist however I have not yet had any feedback as to where to insert this code and why.

```
Sub TableFilt()
Dim PayorName As String
Dim LastRow As Long
With Sheet1
 LastRow = .Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row
 If LastRow < 12 Then LastRow = 12
 If .Range("A11").Value = "Enter Payor Name to Filter" Then PayorName = 
 Empty Else: PayorName = .Range("A11").Value
 .Range("A12:DS" & LastRow).Select
 Selection.AutoFilter
   With .Range("A12:DS" & LastRow)
     If PayorName <> Empty Then .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & 
   PayorName & "*"
  End With
.Range("12:12").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End With
End Sub
```

I would like for the user to have the ability to create the PDF after using an autofilter without being concerned the rows that are hidden are going to be deleted or the information erased once the needed PDF's have been created and they clear out their filter. Can someone please advise? Thank you!

Comment: Try using `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

Comment: Thank you.  I've seen that code as I did research however I honestly have no clue where to insert it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Update the code above with the code that does the auto fill of the PDF file and I may be able to assist with an explanation.

Comment: I apologize - I am not sure where to add .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) within the current code. I added it after the "for CustRow" line but I don't think that's correct. (Or I misunderstood what you were saying)

Comment: No I need to see the code that you are using to load the information from the excel worksheet to the pdf so I can tell you where to use that.

Comment: Again, my apologies - I think I have the right code up now.